# New row in Binded DataGrid shows DatePicker as 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datepicker

Was wondering if you could help me. I have a DataGrid where the user will be adding new rows from within the DataGrid. I have a DatePicker that is bound to an ObersableCollection collection in the ViewModel.

When I create a new row by double-clicking on the last row, the DatePicker defaults to 01/01/0001.

I've tried using a converter as defined here:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    DateTime dateValue = (DateTime)value;
    return dateValue.ToShortDateString() == "01/01/0001" ? DateTime.Now : value;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value;
}
```

And I added this converter to the binding. This shows the UI as DateTime.Now as expected, but when it goes into the ObservableCollection, the DateTime value is still 01/01/0001. Therefore when I am saving the changes to the database, I am getting an error converting DateTime2 to DateTime.

Is there any easy way around this? I'm tempted to not have inline adding if I cannot resolve this problem but I'd rather avoid having to go down that route.

Comment: `when it goes into the ObservableCollection, the DateTime value is still 01/01/0001`. well, it is expected, `Convert` method changes the value displayed in the datagrid, nothing more. before saving the changes to the database check and do smth with `01/01/0001` values

Comment: @ASh Convert is surely useless then? I want the value in the datagrid to mitigate to the ObersableCollection. The actual issue being that when the user goes to select a date, it is starting the DatePicker at 01/01/0001 so is effectively useless. I've tried setting the 'DisplayDateTime' to todays date, but it still starts from 01/01/0001 in the DatePicker Calendar, again, completely useless?

Comment: @Yolomoko, I suppose converter might work if you put in `CovertBack` the same code as in `Convert`

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Exactly how and where do you set the DisplayDateTime property to today's date? You should do this in the constructor of the class or by initializing the field as per my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default value of the `DateTime` property of your data object class, i.e. in the class `T` of the `ObservableCollection<T>` that you have set or bound the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to:

```
private DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.Now; //<-- default value
public DateTime DateTime
{
    get { return _dateTime; }
    set { _dateTime = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using Entity Framework so I presume I'd need to create a partial class for Sailing. I haven't done this before so I'm currently fighting with getting this working and then I will try your suggestion.